# Manually Rendering Django Form with Validation

Tags: django, django-templates

I've started to create a form.  Basically the form is a "test" of twenty words.  The form consists of twenty text fields which I want to contain the definition of a word.  The user would input the word.  Once complete, the form should validate the data and mark what is correct and what isn't.  I've done plenty of modelforms in django, but this one is different.  All the data in this form has to be passed through as context.
**views.py**

```
def get_test(request, username='default'):
    template_name = 'main/test.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass
    else:
        lang = Language(config('USER'), config('PASS'))
        streakinfo = lang.get_streak_info()
        uniquewords = lang.get_unique_words()
        testwords = get_test_words(uniquewords)
        wordsdict = get_word_dict(testwords)
        form = TestForm()
        context = {
            'testwords': testwords, # list of random unique test words
            'wordsdict': wordsdict, # dict of words + definitions {word: {pronounciation, definition}}
            'form': form,
        }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    word_1 = forms.CharField(label='1', max_length=100)
    word_2 = forms.CharField(label='2', max_length=100)
    word_3 = forms.CharField(label='3', max_length=100)
    word_4 = forms.CharField(label='4', max_length=100)
    word_5 = forms.CharField(label='5', max_length=100)
    word_6 = forms.CharField(label='6', max_length=100)
    word_7 = forms.CharField(label='7', max_length=100)
    word_8 = forms.CharField(label='8', max_length=100)
    word_9 = forms.CharField(label='9', max_length=100)
    word_10 = forms.CharField(label='10', max_length=100)
    word_11 = forms.CharField(label='11', max_length=100)
    word_12 = forms.CharField(label='12', max_length=100)
    word_13 = forms.CharField(label='13', max_length=100)
    word_14 = forms.CharField(label='14', max_length=100)
    word_15 = forms.CharField(label='15', max_length=100)
    word_16 = forms.CharField(label='16', max_length=100)
    word_17 = forms.CharField(label='17', max_length=100)
    word_18 = forms.CharField(label='18', max_length=100)
    word_19 = forms.CharField(label='19', max_length=100)
    word_20 = forms.CharField(label='20', max_length=100)
```

I mean, it's simple enough to go through and render each field manually, but what I don't know and have never done is this without a model.  For instance, I want to build up a table, col 1 has the definition (I don't actually need the `label=##` because again, I am passing the data through as context), col 2 has the field.  How do I tie the post data together such that when I post the results, col 2 is most assuredly checked against col 1?  In a nutshell, how can I manually render and validate a form and keep all the data lined up?  I apologize ahead of time if this is to broad of a question.

**Update:**

I was able to get the test data into the form and render the fields with the following ([by hacking away at the forms.Form inheritance](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py)):

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    """
    Student test form
    """    
    def __init__(self, testdict, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.testdict = {} if testdict is None else testdict
        d = self.testdict
        for word in d:
            answer = word
            for key in d[word]:
                value = str(d[word][key])
                if key == 'id':
                    field_name = value
                if key == 'definition':
                    question = value
            self.fields[field_name] = forms.CharField(label=question, max_length=100)
```

Still need help though.

Comment: You need to validate the data that is being entered in this form? that is what you're asking, right?

Comment: what's col 2? Also, could you please post what have you already tried (in the template)? by simply using `{{ form }}` in the template, you will get some insights about what is expected by the django view.

Comment: @ans2human that's part of it yes.

Comment: Got it, gimme few moments for the answer.

Comment: @ans2human col 2 is the field. The user will fill out the field with the answer to the question. Col 1 is the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplished this two ways: one of which includes a file write and the other a model write.  Since writing to models is obviously faster, I will showcase that:

In the view I think it's pretty straight forward.  Here the start of this is that I am passing in the word dictionary to the form when I instantiate the form on a `GET` request `form = TestForm(wordsdict)`.  POST request data is not ever actually stored, just used to validate.  So when I POST, I simply send in the POST data as normal. `wordsdict` is a dictionary composed of a {answer: [question, id]}

**views.py**

```
def language_test(request, username='johndoe', password=None):
    lang= Language(config('USER'), config('PASS'))
    streakinfo = lang.get_streak_info()
    context = {
        'username': username,
        'streakinfo': streakinfo,
    }
    template_name = 'tests/test.html'
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the saved answer dictionary:
        print('POSTING TEST RESULTS')
        form = TestForm(data=request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            print('PASSED')
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return redirect('main:success')
        else:  
            print('FAILED')
            if form.has_error:
                print('FORM ERROR')
            pass
    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        print('GETTING NEW TEST')
        phrases = lang.get_known_phrases()
        testwords = get_test_words(phrases)
        wordsdict = get_word_dict(testwords)
        form = TestForm(wordsdict)
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Straight forward again...

**models.py**

```
class TestAnswers(models.Model):
    phraseid = models.IntegerField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    question = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

Here is where the magic happens.  I'm super'ing the `__init__` function of the inherited `Form` class.  When the class is instantiated, it will evaluate the `test_dict` argument, which may or may not have been passed in by the view.  If there is no `test_dict`, it must be a request for a new test, so I clear out the test model and create a new one with the randomly selected questions\answers passed in by the view.  If there is no `test_dict` passed in, then it must be a post request, meaning I need to validate all the answers.  Refer to the clean method for the form validation.

**forms.py**

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    """
    Student test form
    """    
    def __init__(self, test_dict=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._resource_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'static/json')
        self._json_path = os.path.join(self._resource_path, 'answers.json')
        self._model = TestAnswers
        i = 0
        phraseid, answer, question = [], [], []
        if test_dict is not None:
        # A form get request should resolve new form data and
        # store it in the database for comparison later on
            # clear out the answers table
            self._model.objects.all().delete()
            # create a list of model objects to bulk insert
            records = []
            for item in test_dict:
                record = self._model(
                    phraseid=test_dict[item]['id'],
                    answer=item,
                    question=test_dict[item]['definition']
                )
                phraseid.append(test_dict[item]['id'])
                question.append(test_dict[item]['definition'])
                answer.append(item)
                records.append(record)
            if records:
                # Insert the records into the TestAnswers table
                self._model.objects.bulk_create(records)
            self.test_dict = test_dict

        else:
        # A form post request should check the form data against
        # what was established during the get request
            # Get all the objects in the test table
            records = self._model.objects.all()
            # Put all the object items into their respective lists
            for r in records:
                phraseid.append(r.phraseid)
                answer.append(r.answer)
                question.append(r.question)
        for i in range(len(question)):
            # Set the form fields
            field_name = 'testword' + str(phraseid[i])
            # Print the answers for debugging
            print('id: ' + str(phraseid[i]))
            print('question: ' + question[i])
            print('answer:' + answer[i])
            self.fields[field_name] = forms.CharField(label=question[i], max_length=100)
        self.question = question
        self.phraseid = phraseid
        self.answer = answer

    def clean(self):
        # print('CLEANING DATA')
        phraseid, answer, question = [], [], []
        context = {}
        i = 0
        records = self._model.objects.all()
        for r in records:
            phraseid.append(r.phraseid)
            answer.append(r.answer)
            question.append(r.question)
        # Get and check the results
        for i in range(len(self.cleaned_data)):
            field_name = 'testword' + str(phraseid[i])
            result = self.cleaned_data.get(field_name)
            if result != answer[i]:
                self.add_error(field_name, 'Incorrect')
            context[i] = question[i]
            i += 1
        return context
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can override the clean mehtod and implement your validations on them like this:

You have wrtten all the fields with form class and then using get you actually get what is being entered in those fields by their `name`  HTML parameter and then you manipulate the data by their variables and if they don't match to what exactly you desire then raise a `Validationerror`. Then you're creating a context of all that data from those fields into a dict and setting a variable to it which at the end is returned.

**`forms.py`**

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    word_1 = forms.CharField(label='1', max_length=100)
    word_2 = forms.CharField(label='2', max_length=100)
    word_3 = forms.CharField(label='3', max_length=100)
    word_4 = forms.CharField(label='4', max_length=100)
    word_5 = forms.CharField(label='5', max_length=100)
    word_6 = forms.CharField(label='6', max_length=100)
    word_7 = forms.CharField(label='7', max_length=100)
    word_8 = forms.CharField(label='8', max_length=100)
    word_9 = forms.CharField(label='9', max_length=100)
    word_10 = forms.CharField(label='10', max_length=100)
    word_11 = forms.CharField(label='11', max_length=100)
    word_12 = forms.CharField(label='12', max_length=100)
    word_13 = forms.CharField(label='13', max_length=100)
    word_14 = forms.CharField(label='14', max_length=100)
    word_15 = forms.CharField(label='15', max_length=100)
    word_16 = forms.CharField(label='16', max_length=100)
    word_17 = forms.CharField(label='17', max_length=100)
    word_18 = forms.CharField(label='18', max_length=100)
    word_19 = forms.CharField(label='19', max_length=100)
    word_20 = forms.CharField(label='20', max_length=100)


    def clean(self):

        word_1 = self.cleaned_data.get("word_1")
             #        |
             #        |         write the clean method of all fields
             #        |
             #      ----- 
             #       --- 
             #        - 

        word_20 = self.cleaned_data.get("word_20")



        if word_1 and word_2 and word_7 and word_15 != something:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Something Fishy")
            # i combined few of the word fields but you check all the fields separately also and implement your validation.

        words_context = {
            'word_1':word_1

            #     |               <--write all the context of corresponding fields
            #     |

            'word_20':word_20
        }

        return words_context
```

**`Views.py`**

```
def get_test(request, username='default'):
    template_name = 'main/test.html'
    form = TestForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            word_1 = self.cleaned_data.get("word_1")
             #        |
             #        |         write the clean method of all fields
             #        |
             #      ----- 
             #       --- 
             #        - 
            word_20 = self.cleaned_data.get("word_20")
            newtest = Test(word_1=word_1,....word_20=word_20)
            newtest.save()
            return redirect('whereever you want to redirect')
    else:
        lang = Language(config('USER'), config('PASS'))
        streakinfo = lang.get_streak_info()
        uniquewords = lang.get_unique_words()
        testwords = get_test_words(uniquewords)
        wordsdict = get_word_dict(testwords)
        form = TestForm()
        context = {
            'testwords': testwords, # list of random unique test words
            'wordsdict': wordsdict, # dict of words + definitions {word: {pronounciation, definition}}
            'form': form,
        }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Comment: How am I tieing the fields and data together? In other words how am I making sure word_1 is word_1 and the answer to word_1 is the answer to word_1?  I assume I'm passing the values into the TestForm class when I instantiate it in the view.  But then what?

Comment: I think this will get me started. Don't see how col1 will tie to col2 yet but will probably figure it out in testing.

Comment: Sure, if the solutions helps you don't forget to support it for other readers.

Comment: No doubt. Once I get back to my desk it's play time. :)

Comment: I think, as I suspected, my question was too broad.  I suspect this handles form submission perfectly fine (which helps for sure), but I'm not quite grasping the form generation.  For example, `wordsdict` is a dict that is generated randomly.  `{word: {id, pronounciation, definition}}` is the format of the dict.  Ideally the `id` of the word would be associated to the field of the form e.g. the `name`.  The The form label would also need to be tied to the form field, and the form label is meant to be the "test question".  If I am just increasing confusion here, lmk and I will rework the OP.

Comment: I swear, Django forms are the one thing that slows me down every time I put together a new site project lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188406/discussion-between-ans2human-and-jaberwocky).

Comment: Not sure if you got the link in chat, I posted it there again.  Hopefully you can get back to it.

Comment: If you check the chat (I added my email) or get the link working, youll see some progress.  Still lots to work through though.