# Can there be a general way of extracting 'cleaned_data' from a django form after post? Such that this can be used for any django form

Tags: django, django-forms

I was wondering if we can create a general method that would accept a form instance after POST and extract all fields into a dict with keys same as the field names from the django form.

Comment: take a look, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54684678/manually-rendering-django-form-with-validation/54685097#54685097

Comment: Your question is unclear. `cleaned_data` is already a dict whose keys have the same names as the field in the form.